# how to view errors in the durandal optimizer?

Tags: requirejs, durandal

my optimizer for my durandal project stopped working. i run it in the cmd.exe. any ideas on where i can go to view any errors? it does print out what it's doing, but no errors. it's then failing to produce my main-built.js file. (well, it produces a blank one).

here's what it's outputting:

my project is called 'myapp' for the purposes of this example and it's in c:\projects

```
C:\Projects\myapp\App\durandal\amd>c:\projects\myapp\App\durandal\amd\optimizer.exe --source c:\projects\myapp\app\

Using default base configuration.
Configuring for deploy with almond (custom).
{
  "name": "durandal/amd/almond-custom",
  "inlineText": true,
  "stubModules": [
    "durandal/amd/text"
  ],
  "paths": {
    "text": "durandal/amd/text"
  },
  "baseUrl": "c:\\projects\\myapp\\app\\",
  "mainConfigFile": "c:\\projects\\myapp\\app\\main.js",
  "include": [
    "c:/projects/myapp/app/customViewEngine",
    "c:/projects/myapp/app/main-built",
    "c:/projects/myapp/app/main",
    "c:/projects/myapp/app/durandal/app",
    "c:/projects/myapp/app/durandal/composition",
    "c:/projects/myapp/app/durandal/events",
    "c:/projects/myapp/app/durandal/http",
    "text!c:/projects/myapp/app/durandal/messageBox.html",
    "c:/projects/myapp/app/durandal/messageBox",
    "c:/projects/myapp/app/durandal/modalDialog",
    "c:/projects/myapp/app/durandal/system",
    "c:/projects/myapp/app/durandal/viewEngine",
    "c:/projects/myapp/app/durandal/viewLocator",
    "c:/projects/myapp/app/durandal/viewModel",
    "c:/projects/myapp/app/durandal/viewModelBinder",
    "c:/projects/myapp/app/durandal/widget",
    "c:/projects/myapp/app/durandal/bindings/datePicker",
    "c:/projects/myapp/app/durandal/plugins/router",
    "c:/projects/myapp/app/durandal/transitions/entrance",
    "c:/projects/myapp/app/viewmodels/batchsubmissions",
    "c:/projects/myapp/app/viewmodels/customers",
    "c:/projects/myapp/app/viewmodels/dashboard",
    "c:/projects/myapp/app/viewmodels/emailtitles",
    "c:/projects/myapp/app/viewmodels/entersubmissions",
    "c:/projects/myapp/app/viewmodels/flickr",
    "c:/projects/myapp/app/viewmodels/help",
    "c:/projects/myapp/app/viewmodels/programdetails",
    "c:/projects/myapp/app/viewmodels/shell",
    "c:/projects/myapp/app/viewmodels/titlesetup",
    "c:/projects/myapp/app/viewmodels/welcome",
    "text!c:/projects/myapp/app/views/batchsubmissions.html",
    "text!c:/projects/myapp/app/views/customers.html",
    "text!c:/projects/myapp/app/views/dashboard.html",
    "text!c:/projects/myapp/app/views/detail.html",
    "text!c:/projects/myapp/app/views/emailtitles.html",
    "text!c:/projects/myapp/app/views/entersubmissions.html",
    "text!c:/projects/myapp/app/views/flickr.html",
    "text!c:/projects/myapp/app/views/help.html",
    "text!c:/projects/myapp/app/views/programdetails.html",
    "text!c:/projects/myapp/app/views/shell.html",
    "text!c:/projects/myapp/app/views/titlesetup.html",
    "text!c:/projects/myapp/app/views/welcome.html"
  ],
  "exclude": [],
  "keepBuildDir": true,
  "optimize": "uglify2",
  "out": "c:\\projects\\myapp\\app\\main-built.js",
  "pragmas": {
    "build": true
  },
  "wrap": true,
  "insertRequire": [
    "main"
  ]
}
Deleting old output file.

Tracing dependencies for: durandal/amd/almond-custom
```

Comment: You can run the app.build.js file directly from a cmd window in your amd folder.  At the prompt, type > "node r.js -o app.build.js" Any errors should be displayed by Node

Comment: thanks mikekidder - that looks to be a bit more informative in that it does show actual errors being generated from the r.js (which i believe is doing a lot of the work during the optimizer.exe)

Answer (score 3):

Here are all the options available

1. **--mode** Indicates whether the optimizer should only 'generate' the r.js config or actually 'build' the optimized JS application. Default value build
2. **--source** The path to the folder which contains the application source.
3. **--config** The path to the customized r.js configuration file to be used as a base for the generated configuration.
4. **--verbose** Indicates that verbose console logging should be used. Default value false
5. **--loader** Indicates which script loader to optimize for 'almond' or 'require'. Default value almond
6. **--plugin** The view plugin used to optimize views into the final build file. Default value text
7. **--pluginExtension** The view file extension. Default value .html

Using the optimizer is like so:

```
optimizer.exe --source c:\project1\app\ --mode generate
```

So, maybe you should try this:

```
optimizer.exe --verbose true
```

and if that doesn't work.. then you can always pull down the source and try and debug it locally.